# How can I make a cloud image move in CSS without moving along with the written content in HTML?

Tags: html, css, css-animations, css-transforms

I want the cloud image to move in the background without being attached to the written content. This is what I have done so far. I have attempted other ways, but I still have the same problem.

```css
.intro {
  background-image: url(https://via.placeholder.com/50.jpg);
  position: relative;
  background-repeat: round;
  animation: animatedBackground 5s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes animatedBackground {
  0% {
    background-position: 0 0;
  }
  50% {
    background-position: -20px 0;
  }
  100% {
    background-position: 20px 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<section class="intro" id="zen-intro">
  <header role="banner">
    <h1>CSS Zen Garden</h1>
    <h2>The Beauty of <abbr title="Cascading Style Sheets">CSS</abbr> Design</h2>
  </header>

  <div class="summary" id="zen-summary" role="article">
    <p>A demonstration of what can be accomplished through <abbr title="Cascading Style Sheets">CSS</abbr>-based design. Select any style sheet from the list to load it into this page.</p>
    <p>Download the example <a href="/examples/index" title="This page's source HTML code, not to be modified.">html file</a> and <a href="/examples/style.css" title="This page's sample CSS, the file you may modify.">css file</a></p>
  </div>
```

Comment: What exactly is your problem? This animation should move only with background image, not content.

Comment: Do you mean you don’t want the background to move if the text in the section is scrolled? And what should it look like when the section is only partially within the viewport?

Comment: There is a cloud image. I want it to move across the screen alone. Just a moving cloud.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I still don't understand. In your snippet there is a background image that is moving. That image could be a cloud. So what exactly isn't working?

Comment: The cloud is moving along with the content. I want the cloud to move along alone.